# YAPF seems not to work when there is a comment within a function definition

Tags: python, autoformatting, yapf

I am Using `yapf 0.40.1` with `Python 3.10.4`.

I have a `pyproject.toml` file with the following config:

```
[tool.yapf]
based_on_style='yapf'
column_limit=120
spaces_before_comment=2
continuation_indent_width=2
indent_width=2
coalesce_brackets=true
dedent_closing_brackets=true
```

When running yapf ( `yapf -ir --style pyproject.toml yapf_test.py`), the following code is not formatted (`yapf_test.py` only contains these lines):

```
def x(     # x
  xxxx,
  xxxxxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation, xxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation, xxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation
) -> type_annotation:
  pass
```

when I remove the comment i.e. the `# x` in the first line, it is formatted to

```
def x(
  xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation, xxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation, xxxxxxxxxx: type_annotation
) -> type_annotation:
  pass
```

It seems that the presence of this comment somehow disables yapf. What can I do that it is formatted even if the comment is present? What causes this behavior?
Note that I cannot just get rid of the comment, since this naturally occurs when e.g. silencing `mypy` errors, which have to be on the same line where they occur.